# Craft Folder Error

Tags: permissions, nginx

I switched from Apache to Nginx.  When I did that the Craft folder that was outside of the web root no longer was recognized.  Checked around, dug into my .conf files and spent a boatload on this issue, no dice.  Thinking it was ownership or folder permissions, but I changed /craft folder to 777, made no difference.

Once I brought back in the Craft directory under public_html it was all good.  I would rather it be outside of that.  Have any of you run Nginx and Craft together successfully with the folder being under public_html?

Comment: Were you getting a particular error or message? Did you adjust the `$craftPath` setting in the public index.php file?

Comment: No, I kept everything the same $craftPath = '../craft', when I moved the folder I changed it to $craftPath = './craft'.

Error: Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I further adjusted permissions on the folders again and made a copy (everything with the craft folder in /public_html was working fine), moved that copy back under the public root.  Switched the directory call in index.php and it works now.  Go figure, it was permissions after all.